# How to correctly add a labor transaction record in a Maximo automation script

Tags: automation, maximo

Hi I'm trying to add a labor transaction from an action automation script with the object being ASSIGNMENT in Maximo. I am currently trying the code below.

```
labTransSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("LABTRANS",ui);
labTrans = labTransSet.add();
labTrans.setValue("laborcode", userLabor);
labTrans.setValue("wonum", assignWonum);
sds1=SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm aa").format(firstDate);
sds2=SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm aa").format(Date());
labTrans.setValue("STARTTIME", sds1);
labTrans.setValue("FINISHTIME", sds2);
labTransSet.save();
labTransSet.close();
```

userLabor is the username of the current user

assignWonum is the assignment work order number

firstDate is the scheduled date field from the assignment

The labor record is being added correctly with the right data, but when I go to route my workflow after the script is called from a button, I am given the warning BMXAA8229W WOACTIVITY has been updated by another user and the work order does not route. I am under the impression that this is happening because the assignment object for the script is being queried at the same time I try to add and save a labor record. Does anyone know if my guess is correct or what else the problem is and how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: How is this script running? Is this firing from a button press in your work order application? On an object or attribute launch point (and if so, what exactly is the launch point)? From an escalation or cron task? From an action line in the workflow itself?

Comment: The automation script has an action launch point and is firing from a button. The object associated with it is ASSIGNMENT.

Answer (score 3):

That error occurs because Maximo already has one version of the record loaded into memory when the record in the database is modified independently. Maximo then tries to work with the in-memory object and sees it doesn't match what is in the database and throws that error. Timing doesn't really have anything to do with it (other than that an edit happened at some point after the record was loaded into memory).

What you need to do is make sure you are modifying the exact same task/assignment/labtrans record that has already been loaded into memory. That "MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet" stuff is guaranteed to use a new object. That is how you start a new transaction in Maximo; how you make sure you are not using anything already loaded into memory. I suspect you want to get your set off of the implicit "mbo" object the script will give to you.

Comment: I had the same impression, but when I tried to use the mbo to get the labor transaction and add a row it gave an error telling me it couldn't find LABTRANS. I was using "mbo.getMboSet("LABTRANS")", is this the incorrect way to fetch from the mbo?

Comment: Check the MAXRELATIONSHIP table for parent='ASSIGNMENT' and child='LABTRANS'

Comment: As JPTremblay says, you need to be using Maximo's relationships when getting a set off of an MBO like that (you use the object names when starting a new transaction (from MXServer), but use relationship names when using an existing MBO/transaction). In this case, the relationship name from assignment to labtrans is "LABTRANSCREW".

Comment: Also, for note, the "save()" and "close()" calls may not be needed (or wanted) with the new way of fetching the set, but that's a more advanced topic that may not be relevant.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have fixed my problem and it is working correctly now.